# Como imprimir o vetor de um objeto em Java?

Tags: java

Estou praticando o que venho aprendendo em Java, e travei em uma parte, que estou tentando listar alguns livros de um array que está no objeto Livros, porém quando eu coloco a classe no System.out.print aparece isso Livros@6576fe71, aparenta ser o local de armazenamento.

```
public class Biblioteca {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    Livros livros = new Livros();


    int operacao;

    cadastro();

    do {
        System.out.println("======================= Bem vindo a Biblioteca digital =======================");
        System.out.println("Escolha uma das opções abaixo:");
        System.out.println("1-Emprestimo\n2-Lista de livros\n3-Sair");
        operacao = ler.nextInt();

        switch (operacao){
            case 1:
                emprestimo();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println(livros);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Escolha uma das opções!");
                break;
        }

    }while(operacao != 3);
}
```

e o Objeto Livros

```
public class Livros {
    String [] livros = {"O labirinto do fauno","Seja o amor da sua vida","O corpo fala"};
}
```

Comment: Uma maneira de resolver o problema é sobreescrever o método `toString()` da classe `Livros`. Mas vai precisar percorrer todo o array de livros (o atributo da classe `Livros`). Um exemplo de implementação pode ser visto [aqui](https://gist.github.com/danizavtz/02193b909c63cdc754d81a811bc71419)

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Comment: Se quer imprimir os elementos de um array, a solução mais simples é percorrê-lo com um loop e imprimir um a um os dados de cada elemento, no formato que vc precisa. Claro que sobrescrever `toString` (como já indicado pelas respostas abaixo) também funciona e pode ou não ser suficiente, dependendo do caso. Ver também: [Qual é a função do método toString()?](/q/212754/112052)

Answer (score 2):

#### Por que imprimiu `Livros@6576fe71`?

O problema do seu código é que na linha...

```
System.out.println(livros);
//Livros@6576fe71
```

...houve uma tentativa de imprimir a instância de uma classe cujo o método de instância [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) não foi sobrescrito e portanto foi utilizado  a implementação herdada da classe fundamental [`java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) que está documentado como se segue:

> **`public String toString()`**
> Retorna uma representação em string do objeto.
> **Observação da API:**
> Em geral, o método `toString()` retorna uma cadeia de caracteres que "representa textualmente" esse objeto. O resultado
> deve ser uma representação concisa, mas informativa, que seja fácil de
> ser lida por uma pessoa. Recomenda-se que todas as subclasses
> substituam esse método. A saída da cadeia de caracteres não é
> necessariamente estável ao longo do tempo ou entre as invocações da
> *JVM*.
> **Requisitos de implementação:**
> O método `toString()` da classe `Object` retorna uma cadeia de caracteres que consiste no nome da classe da
> qual o objeto é uma instância, o caractere de sinal de arroba `@` e a
> representação hexadecimal sem sinal do código de hash do objeto. Em
> outras palavras, esse método retorna uma cadeia de caracteres igual ao
> valor de:
> `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`
> **Retorna:**
> Uma representação em string do objeto.

#### Por que `println()` chama `toString()`?

Isso ocorre devido ao funcionamento do método  [`java.io.PrintStream.println(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)), veja sua documentação:

> **`public void println(Object x)`**
> Imprime um objeto e, em seguida, encerra a linha. Esse método chama inicialmente
> `String.valueOf(x)` para obter o valor da cadeia de caracteres do
> objeto impresso e, em seguida, comporta-se como se invocasse
> `print(String)` e, depois, `println()`.
> **Parâmetros:**
> x - O objeto a ser impresso.

E por sua vez a documentação [`String.valueOf(x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)):

> **`public static String valueOf(Object obj)`**
> Retorna a representação em string do argumento Object.
> **Parâmetros:**
> obj - um Object.
> **Retorna:**
> se o argumento for `null`, então uma cadeia de caracteres igual a `"null"`; caso contrário, o valor de
> `obj.toString()` é retornado.

Então ao fazer `System.out.println(livros);` lança essa sequência de eventos:

- `println(livros)` chamou `String.valueOf(livros)`,
- `String.valueOf(livros)` chamou `livros.toString()`
- `livros.toString()` chamou `Object.toString()`
- `Object.toString()` retornou `livros.getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(livros.hashCode())`

#### Mas se fizesse `System.out.println(livros.livros);`?

Caso tentasse imprimir a propriedade `livros.livros` o resultado não seria muito diferente, veja:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Livros livros = new Livros();
 
        System.out.println(livros.livros);
        //[Ljava.lang.String;@5caf905d
    }
}

class Livros {
    String [] livros = {"O labirinto do fauno","Seja o amor da sua vida","O corpo fala"};
}
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Dqryzc)</sup>

Como visto o [Exemplo Mínimo Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) o retornou `[Ljava.lang.String;@5caf905d` em `System.out.println(livros.livros);` pelos mesmo motivo anteriormente descrito, a única diferença é que em `[Ljava.lang.String;@5caf905d` aparece o prefixo `[L` que é [descritor de campo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3) para objetos do tipo array.

#### Como imprimir um array em Java?

Em Java antes de imprimir um vetor em uma [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html) uma alternativa pode ser convertê-lo em uma [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.htm).
Em java a conversão de *Array de string* pode ser realizada de várias formas, e uma dessas formas é usando o método [`java.lang.String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable)) que retorna um novo `String` composto pelas cópias dos elementos de um iterável unidos por um delimitador. No exemplo abaixo o delimitador utilizado foi o caractere de quebra de linha da plataforma que estiver o código, obtido via o método [`java.lang.System.getProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) usando como argumento [`"line.separator"`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties())

```
String [] livros = {"O labirinto do fauno", "Seja o amor da sua vida", "O corpo fala"};
        
System.out.println(String.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), livros));
//O labirinto do fauno
//Seja o amor da sua vida
//O corpo fala
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/fswjhM)</sup>

Com essa fundamentação você pode então decidir se apenas modifica a linha `System.out.println(livros);`...

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Livros livros = new Livros();
 
        System.out.println(String.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), livros.livros));
        //O labirinto do fauno
        //Seja o amor da sua vida
        //O corpo fala
    }
 
}
 
class Livros {
    String [] livros = {"O labirinto do fauno","Seja o amor da sua vida","O corpo fala"};
}
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/YivM4P)</sup>
...ou sobrescreva o método `toString()` na classe `Livros`:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Livros livros = new Livros();
        
        System.out.println(livros);
        //O labirinto do fauno
        //Seja o amor da sua vida
        //O corpo fala
    }
}

class Livros {
    String [] livros = {"O labirinto do fauno","Seja o amor da sua vida","O corpo fala"};
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), livros);
    }
}
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/0Cc0Gp)</sup>

Comment: está estudando Java agora?

Comment: @Danizavtz Eu comecei a estudar Java quando criaram. Por volta de 2005 eu comecei a deixar de lado trocando por C#.

Comment: muito bom, a comunidade só tem a ganhar!

Answer (score 1):

Sobre-escrever o método toString de classes definidas pelo usuário te permite ter uma representação mais significativa dos seus objetos.

A implementação do método `toString` da classe [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) está definido da seguinte forma:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Isto retorna uma string que consiste no nome da classe da qual o objeto é uma instância, o caractere de arroba `@' e a representação hexadecimal não assinada do código hash do objeto.

Em geral, o método toString retorna uma string que "representa em forma de texto" este objeto. O resultado deve ser uma representação concisa, mas informativa, de fácil leitura para uma pessoa. É recomendado que todas as subclasses sobre-escrevam este método.

#### Entendendo o que está acontecendo

Como não sobre-escreveu o método toString, seu objeto está "exibindo" a implementação concreta que foi definido na classe `Object`.

Mas como? Se a minha classe não possui o método toString()?

Como você não implementou explicitamente este método ele faz a mesma coisa que o método toString da classe Object, pois toda estrutura de dados (no seu caso é o objeto `Livros`) definida pelo usuário herda de `Object` (isso é uma regra em Java, mas não da orientação à objetos). Neste caso a sua classe `Livros` está herdando a implementaçao do método toString via herança.

### Implementação concreta

Sabendo disto, agora podemos sobre-escrever o método toString, para representar o nosso objeto de uma maneira mais representativa. Como o objeto possui um atributo `livros` que é um array de String, então devemos percorrer (iterar) todo o array e exibir cada item. Isso pode ser feito utilizando um laço de repetição `for`.

Uma implementação do método `toString` da classe `Livros` seria a seguinte:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (var l: livros) {
        str.append(l).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```

Implementei utilizando a classe [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) por questões de eficiência e desempenho Já que o utilizando o StringBuilder vamos criar um objeto e fazer operações de concatenação neste mesmo objeto, montando a minha representação do objeto, que é simplesmente percorrer um a um os itens da lista.

O método `getProperty` é uma implementação que deixa o seu código independente de plataforma ao utilizar a quebra de linha. Desta maneira, estou utilizando a VM Java para interagir com o sistema operacional para usar a representação adequada do caractere  `quebra de linha`.